# Pandas GroupBy error occurs only in large dataset

Tags: pandas, group-by

I use such code to select rows with max value in gropus:

```
set_f = set.loc[set.reset_index().groupby(['Scan Number'])['dda246displmils'].idxmax()]
```

and this works perfectly fine with dataset od ~1M rows but i get this error when try to group 38M rows:

*KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%27)*

What is the reason? Is there any other option for bigger dataset?

Thanks,
Paulina

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you want select original index values by new created by `reset_index`, so raise error.

Solution is reassign back before `loc`:

```
df = set.reset_index()
set_f = df.loc[df.groupby(['Scan Number'])['dda246displmils'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: It didn't help - still receive the same error.

Comment: @Paulina - What is `print (df.index)` ?